# How much salt in a cup of water would it take to neither hydrate nor dehydrate the average person?

Tags: aqueous-solution, biochemistry, salt

I don't know a lot about chemistry, and this question came up during lunch with my friend. I was interested in this question so I thought I could ask here. Sorry if I didn't use the right tags.

Comment: Isotonic saline, which is 9.0 g salt per liter (= 2.1 g/ 8-oz. cup) is used to maintain fluid balance. But I don't know if "maintaining fluid balance" means neither hydrating nor dehydrating--e.g., it could be hydrating since, to maintain flluid balance, you need to make up for fluid loss.  That might be a question better posed on Biology SE.

Comment: Is the saline for drinking, intravenous injection or taking a bath?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a human physiology question. As `theorist` said, theoretically, an isotonic saline solution (0.9% NaCl) wouldn't hydrate or de-hydrate a person, and it prepared at this concentration because it matches the osmolarity of blood plasma. But it may be administered intravenously to patients in a hypotonic dehydration state, for example, so the amount of salt in a cup of water--or in a solution administered to a patient, for that matter--would have to vary, depending on the hydration state of the person. Also, from an osmosis ("hydration") point of view, many other substances can have the same effect on the body as salt (e.g.: sugar).